# How to send messages by socket.io to specific logged in users after certain events?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I take a few step into socket.io. It's very hard to code without req, because I don't know response to who.

For this question. My website have some blogs. When the blogs updated , I need to 'tell' users who followed the blogs that the blogs have been updated. The problems are I don't know witch followed users are online and I don't know how to emit events to them with only followed user id.

Can some one give me some tips? No need any specific code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of cookies to map http requests to corresponding socket connection. Lets say we are using cookie `sesson-id`.
Drop this cookie on client on a http request.

In the following patch of code, before creating a new socket connection, you attach `session-id` cookie to the socket header. This way you can access this `session-id` in `.on("connection")` event:

```
   var io = require("socket.io");
   sio = io.listen(server);
   sio.set("authorization", function (data, accept) {
     if (data.headers.cookie) {
       data.cookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
       data.headers.sessionID = data.cookie["session-id"];
     }
     accept(null, true);
   });
```

Next, you store socket connection objects associated to their `session-id`:

```
   var sockets = {}; // store all socket connections here
   sio.sockets.on("connection",connected);
   function connected(socket){
      var sessionID = socket.handshake.headers.sessionID;
      sockets[sessionID] = socket;
   }
```

Now, whenever you wish to emit socket event related to a particular http request:

```
  function dummyReq(req,res){
    var session_id = // get cookie from req

    //after certain actions
      sockets[session_id].emit("dummy-event","dummy-message");
  }
```

In your case you will have to emit socket events for all `session-id` linked to users who are following those blogs

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I have though this way before, but finally, I give up because this was too complicate. After that, I dig out some interesting variables. I can get session value just by "io.sockets.sockets[i].request.session". PS: io.set function has been deprecated we should use io.use middleware instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `join` to subscribe the socket to a given channel:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

And then simply use `to` when broadcasting or emitting:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

To leave a channel, you need to call `leave` :

```
io.on('disconnect', function(socket){
  socket.leave('some room');
});
```